# Set filename to ditamap title in DITA-OT Command Line PDF transformation

Tags: dita, dita-ot

I have a script that builds a system on a regular schedule, and as part of that system, I need to convert several documents from dita to PDF.
I can run the following shaped command line from my script fine:

```
dita --input=<file location> --output=<output location> --format=pdf
```

But due to naming conventions and other restrictions, the name of the ditamap files are not always well-formed or human-readable (and I am not able to change the name of the files). I'm aware of the `outputBase.file` parameter that I can pass in on the command line, but I would like dita to be able to scan/read the file and substitute the document title as the filename, something along the lines of:

```
dita --input=<file> --output=<output> --format=pdf --outputBase.file=$title
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change `dita` command-line formats. Instead, you can change output PDF file name to the document title according to following steps:

1. In the top of the your PDF plug-in processing, read the main map's title (bookmap or map) using XSLT task and output XML file that contains title.
2. Set the title to some property you prefer (such as `document.title`). To set property, it is useful to use `<xmlproperty>` task in ant script.
3. After generating PDF file, change the PDF file name in `<output location>` to `${document.title}.pdf` in the last phase of build process.

In my experience, one of the user want to output PDF that is authored in `bookmap`. In this case, above technique works fine for this user.

Hope this helps your development.